# How do i get all the classes of sun.font in jdk9

Tags: java, java-9

I have my old codebase which currently uses **java8**.

I am migrating my codebase to use **jdk9-ea**. But it looks like all the sun.font classes are now not available like the way they used to be earlier

```
error: package sun.font does not exist
```

More specifically i am using

- CompositeFont
- Font2D
- FontDesignMetrics
- FontManager
- FontManagerFactory
- SunFontManager

and more..

Comment: You don't. There has been a warning in the Javadoc about not using `sun.*` classes for at least 20 years. Fix the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A feature of the module system is that it allows library developers to strongly encapsulate implementation details due to the new [accessibility rules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#accessibility). In a nutshell, most types in `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` packages will no longer be accessible. This is in line with Sun and later Oracle stating that these packages are not meant for public consumption.

A workaround is to export these packages at compile and launch time with a command line flag:

```
--add-exports java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This exports the package `sun.font` from the module *java.desktop* to all modules including the [unnamed module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module), which is the one that collects all classes on the class path.